# PYQT5 Make textedit not editable but link clickable (selectable)

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a textedit box that I do not want the user to be able to edit so I used the property: `self.textEdit.setReadOnly(True)` I do however have a link in the text that I would like the user to have the ability to click. `setReadOnly(True)` also disables the link. Is there a way to make my link clickable, but leave the text not editable?

Comment: Why not use a textBrowser? Does the user have to edit the url at one point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dont want to use a textBrower, maybe the command

```
self.textEdit.setTextInteractionFlags(QtCore.Qt.LinksAccessibleByMouse)
```

will be a start for selecting the url when ReadOnly is set to true. You would have to implement a function to connect the selection of the link to a function (one like QTextBrowser already has). You can for example copy the link.
However, i would recommend to use a TextBrowser:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(400, 300)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(Dialog)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(Dialog)
        self.textBrowser.setReadOnly(True)
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.textBrowser, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Dialog)
        self.textEdit.setReadOnly(True)
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        self.textEdit.setTextInteractionFlags(QtCore.Qt.LinksAccessibleByMouse)
        self.textBrowser.setOpenExternalLinks(True)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.textBrowser.setHtml(_translate("Dialog", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\">This is a TextBrowser</p>\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><a href=\"https://www.google.de\"><span style=\" font-size:8pt; text-decoration: underline; color:#0000ff;\">www.google.de</span></a></p></body></html>"))
        self.textEdit.setHtml(_translate("Dialog", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\">This is a TextEdit</p>\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><a href=\"https://www.google.de\"><span style=\" font-size:8pt; text-decoration: underline; color:#0000ff;\">www.google.de</span></a></p></body></html>"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```